# set datetimepicker format as system date format

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a datetimepicker control ploted on datagridview in windows application.
I want the datetimepicker format to be exactly like the system datetime format.
Is it possible?

Comment: what date time picker control are you using?  Can you show us your code please.

Comment: What kind of format you want to use? This type : MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy or dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss or else?

Answer (score 1):

You can set it using

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time
```

Time property will set the format using the format by user's system

Answer (score 0):

"The date/time format is based on the user's regional settings in their operating system."  Which means that it should already be in the format that your system is using.

Here is a link for the default .net (c#)  date time picker, how to set up the format in a specific way: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.format.aspx

Example:

```
public void 
SetMyCustomFormat()
{
   // Set the Format type and the CustomFormat string.
   dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
   dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy - dddd";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DateTimePicker can be used to set a DateTime variable using it's Value property:

```
DateTime myDateTime = dateTimePicker1.Value;
```

The value property is of the same type as system DateTime. How you format you dated when converting to a string is up to you. You can use:

```
myDateTime.ToLongDateString();
outputs: "22 August 2013"

myDateTime.ToLongTimeString();
outputs: "13:20:30"

myDateTime.ToShortDateString();
outputs: "22/08/2013" (in the UK) or "08/22/2013" elsewhere depending on regional settings

myDateTime.ToShortTimeString();
outputs: "13:20"
```

Or do custom formatting such as:

```
myDateTime.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
outputs: "21-Aug-2013 13:20:30"
```

To set the *displayed* format of the DateTimePicker please see Bagzli's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem this way:

```
   DateTimeFormatInfo sysFormat = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
   string sysdatepick = sysFormat.ShortDatePattern;
   string systimepick = sysFormat.LongTimePattern;
   dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = sysdatepick + systimepick;
```